# Cron job + new table vs materialized views for webapp analytics?

Tags: postgresql, analytics

Hi

I am in the process of adding analytics to my SaaS app, and I'd love to hear other people's experiences doing this.

Current I see two different approches:

1. Do most of the data handling at the DB level, building and aggregating data into materialized views for performance boost. This way the data will stay normalized.
2. Have different cronjobs/processes that will run at different intervals (10 min, 1 hour etc.) that will query the database and insert aggregate results into a new table. In this case, the metrics/analytics are denormalized.

Which approach makes the most sense, maybe something completely different?

Answer (score 2):

On really big data, the cronjob or ETL is the only option. You read the data once, aggregate it and never go back. Querying aggregated data is then relatively cheap.

Views will go through tables. If you use "explain" for a view-based query, you might see the data is still being read from tables, possibly using indexes (if corresponding indexes exist). Querying terabytes of data this way is not viable.

The only problem with the cronjob/ETL approach is that it's PITA to maintain. If you find a bug on production environment - you are screwed. You might spend days and weeks fixing and recalculating aggregations. Simply said: you have to get it right the first time :)

Comment: He did say "materialized" views, which physically store the data and not go through tables.